# Facility to restart applications running on a Windows Server

Tags: windows, application

I am currently running Monitis on a few Windows Servers and I'm looking for a tool that would restart an application (exe file) if it crashes or consumes too much memory.  Please could you provide any recommendations for such tools?

Many Thanks,

Tim Harvey

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [SRVANY.EXE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890) from Microsoft.  It'll allow you to run an .exe as a service; once defined as service, you can set up dependencies, recovery, etc.

Another option would be to write a batch/script file that runs every x minute/hour, polls for current processes and if your.exe isn't running, starts it again.